# How to print a pattern using nested for loops?

Tags: c

How do I make my code have an output like this:

```
Enter your number: 4
1 1 1 2
2 2 2 3
3 3 3 4
4 4 4 5
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make it so the last digit prints the next value iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int num;
    int i = 1;

    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(i = 1; i<=num; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<num; ++j)
        {
           printf("%d ",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: One simple way is for the inner loop to stop at `num-1` instead of `num`. Then just have an extra `printf("%d", i+1);` after that loop.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this using nested loops are simple and doesn't require any kind of special calculations, `if`-statements or other more or less fancy stuff. Just keep it simple.

Your task is:

```
for each row:
    print "rowindex+1 and a space" n-1 times
    print "rowindex+2 and a newline" 1 time
```

*"for each row"* is one simple loop.

*"n-1 times"* is another (nested) simple loop.

So keep it simple... just two ordinary for-loops like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  // for each row
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) // n-1 times
        {
            printf("%d ", i + 1);
        }

        printf("%d\n", i + 2);  // 1 time
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something kind of from out in the left field, and off topic, leaving behind not only the requirements of the homework, but the C language. However, we will find our way back.

We can solve this problem (sort of) using text processing at the Unix prompt:

We can treat the smallest square

```
12
23
```

as an initial seed kernel, which is fed through a little command pipeline to produce a square of the next size (up to a single digit limitation):

We define this function:

```
next()
{
  sed -e 's/\(.\).$/\1&/' | awk '1; END { print $0 | "tr \"[1-9]\" \"[2-8]\"" }'
}
```

Then:

```
$ next
12
23
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
112
223
334
```

Now, copy the 3x3 square and paste it into `next`:

```
$ next
112
223
334
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
1112
2223
3334
4445
```

Now, several steps in one go, by piping through multiple instances of `next`:

```
$ next | next | next | next | next
12
23
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
1111112
2222223
3333334
4444445
5555556
6666667
7777778
```

The text processing rule is:

1. For each line of input, repeat the second-to-last character. E.g `ABC` becomes `ABBC`, or `1112` becomes `11112`. This is easily done with `sed`.
2. Add a new line at the end which is a copy of the last line, with each digit replaced by its successor. E.g. if the last line is `3334`, make it `4445`. The `tr` utility helps here

To connect this to the homework problem: a C program could be written which works in a similar way, starting with an array which holds the `1 2` `2 3` square, and grows it.   The requirement for nested loops would be satisfied because there would be an outer loop iterating on the number of "next" operations, and then an inner loop performing the edits on the array: replicating the next-to-last column, and adding the new row at the bottom.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 25

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    fputs("wrong usage\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int n = atoi(argv[1]);

  if (n <= 2 || n > DIM) {
    fputs("invalid n\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int array[DIM][DIM] = {
    { 1, 2 },
    { 2, 3 }
  };

  /* Grow square from size 2 to size n */
  for (int s = 2; s < n; s++) {
    for (int r = 0; r < s; r++) {
      array[r][s] = array[r][s-1];
      array[r][s-1] = array[r][s-2];
    }
    for (int c = 0; c <= s; c++) {
      array[s][c] = array[s-1][c] + 1;
    }
  }

  /* Dump it */
  for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
      printf("%3d ", array[r][c]);
    putchar('\n');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int n;

printf("Enter the number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(int i =1; i<=n; i++){
     for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) {
        if(j==n) 
            printf("%d\t",i+1);
        else
        printf("%d\t",i);
     }
     printf("\n");
}
return 0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nested loops will drive you crazy, trying figure out their boundaries.

While I usually oppose adding more variables, in this case it seems justified to keep track of things simply.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n = 4, val = 1, cnt1 = 1, cnt2 = 0;

    for( int i = 1; i < n*n+1; i++ ) { // notice the 'square' calculation
        printf( "%d ", val );
        if( ++cnt1 == n ) // tired of this digit? start the next digit
            cnt1 = 0, val++;
        if( ++cnt2 == n ) // enough columns output? start the next line
            cnt2 = 0, putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
1 1 1 2
2 2 2 3
3 3 3 4
4 4 4 5
```

A single example of desired output is hard to go by, especially when the code doesn't help... Anyway, here's the output when 'n' = 5.

```
1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 3
3 3 3 3 4
4 4 4 4 5
5 5 5 5 6
```

Comment: ...but this does not use _nested_ loops. Perhaps we should ask if the nested loop is a requirement?

Comment: @Dúthomhas You are correct. No nesting here. But, clean, clear, concise code that delivers the results (as I understand them to be.) Shall I start working on the version that uses everyone's favourite: _recursion_? It's just as likely that the question could be "I'm trying to use recursion to achieve this result..." and then... SO answers should point to practical solutions, not arcane "contort this method with incomprehensible code to apply a method that is not appropriate..." I come down on the side of what I consider "sensible", rather than "arcane"...

Comment: I dunno. I can think of a simple, easy to read, sensible and very much _not_ “arcane” way to do it with nested loops as stated. I very much dislike telling students _do it this way instead of what your professor prescribed_, especially when the instructed way is Not Wrong.

Comment: @Dúthomhas It seems another answer has made explicit your commendable "teaching & guiding" answer. I look at the if/else (some condition) nested inside a for() loop (with its boundaries and conditions) nested inside another for() loop (with ITS boundaries and conditions.) And, then there's a +1 sometimes... It's a lousy assignment to prescribe the method and the output, stifling a student's ability to decompose a problem and assemble a solution (imho). There are many ways to skin most cats. Student's should be left to explore the space, not confined to a particular well-trodden path, imho...

Comment: Yeah, I agree. At the CS 101 level, though, I think well-trodden is necessary. The problem is, I think, too little effort and imagination to struggle with a solution. The internet kind of ruined all that.

Comment: Want me to post a cool _arcane_ way of doing it?

Comment: @Dúthomhas (Knowing it won't be _arcane_,) I (and others) would be delighted to see your code... `:-)` Please edit it onto the end of your answer. `:-)` (and forgive my to often judgemental tone...) `:-)`

Comment: Done. Heh, hope y’all enjoy.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Re: "won't be arcane"... I may have spoken (typed) too soon... `:-)`

Answer (score -1):

#### *All* of these kinds of assignments are to try to get you to recognize a *pattern*.

The pattern you are given

```
1 1 1 2
2 2 2 3
3 3 3 4
4 4 4 5
```

is *very* close to

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

which is an easy nested loop. Write a solution to the easier pattern. Once you have that you can then you can fix it.

Hint: Notice that the only thing that changes is the *last* item of the *inner* loop.

##### Edit

This totally breaks the spirit of the assignment, and if you, dear student, ever try to submit something like this your professor will... probably not care, but also know full well that you didn’t do it. If *I* were your professor you’d lose marks, even if I knew you weren’t cheating and had written something this awesome yourself.

Single loop. Stuff added to pretty print numbers wider than one digit (except the very *last*). Maths, yo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void print_off_by_one_square( int n )
{
  int width = (int)log10( n ) + 1;
  for (int k = 0;  k++ < n*n ;)
    printf( "%*d%c", width, (k+n)/n, (k%n) ? ' ' : '\n' );
}

int main(void)
{
  int n;
  printf( "n? " );
  fflush( stdout );
  if ((scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1) || (n < 0))
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", "Not cool, man, not cool at all." );
  else
    print_off_by_one_square( n );
  return 0;
}
```

The way it works is pretty simple, actually, but I’ll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out on his or her own.

Comment: A work of art! Truly... As "accessible" for the lay-person as a work by Jackson Pollock... `:-)` Have you considered using a `!` to replace the trenary SP v. LF with `" \n"[ !(k%n) ]` (untested... may need to swap the chars... `:-)` (I simply love seeing these things taken to extremes...) Can I download it and test it? `:-)`

Comment: Awww, I’m blushing. [Kaz’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982985/2706707) has the logic in this — he just didn’t quite do the math like I did. The array index trick is one I have often done when playing compiler to trim cycles. It is especially effective when _multiple_ conditions need to be satisfied. I expect the compiler does a pretty good job of optimizing this trinary, though I haven’t bothered to check the assembly to see if it really is overdone. (Oh, and feel free to do whatever you want with code found on the internet. I think everything on SO is CCBYSA or something like that.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a different concept. Some of the answers are based on the idea that we first think about

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

and then tweak the logic for the item in the last line.

But we can regard it like this also:

We have a tape which goes like this:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

and we are blindly cutting the tape into four-element pieces to form a 4x4 square. Suppose someone deletes the first item from the tape, and then adds 5:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5
```

Now, if we cut **that** tape blindly by the same process, we will get the required output:

```
1 1 1 2
2 2 2 3
3 3 3 4
4 4 4 5
```

Suppose we have a linear index through the tape, a position `p` starting at 0.

In the unshifted tape, item `p` is calculated using  `p / 4 + 1`, right?

In the shifted tape, this is just `(p + 1) / 4 + 1`.  Of course we substitute the square size for 4.

Thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    fputs("wrong usage\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int m = n * n;

  if (n <= 0) {
    fputs("invalid n\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  for (int p = 0; p < m; p++) {
    printf("%3d ", (p + 1) / n + 1);
    if (p % n == n - 1)
      putchar('\n');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./square 2
  1   2 
  2   3 
$ ./square 3
  1   1   2 
  2   2   3 
  3   3   4 
$ ./square 4
  1   1   1   2 
  2   2   2   3 
  3   3   3   4 
  4   4   4   5
```

Comment: Excellent thinking, and exactly right... except it doesn’t need _nested_ loops as specified in the title text. Thanks for taking the time to show the thinking though.